# Where is Metadata of Encoding in Plain Text Saved from TextEdit

Tags: textedit, metadata, encoding

TextEdit allows for plain text `.txt` files to be saved with a particular character encoding:

[image]

Is there any meaningful change to the file's metadata and if so, how do you see it?

Comment: I don't hink the encoding is saved anywhere. You have to explicitly manually tell which encoding to use

Comment: @mmmmmm follow-up question, why provide these options?

Comment: See [BOM (Byte order mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: But only UTF-16 will have BOM , is that correct?

Comment: Texted it internally uses utf8 representation on writing out it needs to know what representation to use. The output file will differ. Eg what do you write out when the screen shows an emoji or £ or a Chinese character or ê

Comment: The code for texted it is part of the xcode examples so you can see

Comment: @mmmmmm I don't see a difference between many of the encodings outside of UTF-16, for instance Wester ASCII shows no `hexdump` diff compared to UTF-8. Is there any kind of test text that would illustrate how the encoding option effects the output? Or is this option partially arbitrary?

Comment: You need characters that are not inascii 7 bit try some of the ones I suggested.

Comment: @mmmmmm I have and regardless of the encoding, text is rendered the same.